# Breathing technique Swings

Tags: kettlebell

What is the right breathing technique to get optimal output when doing swings ? I do now breath in when the the kettlebell moves backward and out when it is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's it.  Typically a good rule of thumb is to breath out when the weight is traveling against gravity.